# What does JS return when asked for myArray[index] when index = -1

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to convert a Javascript script to C# and in one of its for loops occasionally a variable is set to the value of another arrays -1 index i.e.

`var newVar = oldVar[index];//But sometimes index = -1`

Obviously C# throws an out of bounds error here but Javascript does not, so what I am wondering is will newVar be equal to oldVar[0] or 'undefined'.

The actual code in question is this

```
feature[k].px[q] = orig_feature[k].px[q] * 4 + orig_feature[k].py[q] * step[orig_feature[k].pz[q]];
```

but when setting the index of 'step' at the end, orig_feature[k].pz[q] sometimes equals -1

Comment: If you try to access an array with an undefined index the way you're doing, `newVar` will be `undefined`, it won't throw an error. You can test this easily yourself -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0r6mpk7m/

Comment: That's pretty easy to test by yourself. Just enter `[][-1]` in your console.

Comment: Or `var a=[];a[-1]=42; a[-1] ` (which will show 42)... It may be better to make JavaScript to behave the way you expect first, than convert to C#.

Comment: Ok so in that case regards the actual code I posted feature[k].px[q] could sometimes end up with a value of NaN right? so I suppose that doesnt cause any errors because if you do NaN <= 1, JS returns false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing an array anywhere that is not defined will return `undefined`.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

array[-1] === undefined
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image. (Also that is at best half of an answer).

Answer (score -1):

No easy way to convert javascript to C# since C# is a stronly typed language and javascript no.
Javascript is trasparent language C# is opaque..

The best i can think is to use emulation or script or compilation, to convert javascript in something that can be executed in C# context (and at runtime).

Try to see JInt :
https://jint.codeplex.com/

Comment: While the OP is doing a code conversion, the question itself is in no way about that process itself, rather the behaviour of OOB in javascript arrays.